# Binario de TensorFlow no se compiló para usar AVX AVX2

Tags: redes-neuronales, tensorflow

Recién instalé TensorFlow en Windows 10 amd64 y cuando corro el primer ejemplo, me dá la siguiente alerta:
`2017-11-01 16:00:17.727925: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2`
Aquí les dejo el "Hola mundo" que hice:

```
import tensorflow as tf

hello = tf.constant('Hello TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))

a = tf.constant(10)
b = tf.constant(32)
print(sess.run(a + b))

sess.close()
```

Después del warning me devuelve la respuesta

`b'Hello TensorFlow!'
42`
¿Alguien me podría decir porque sucede esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es solo una advertencia/aviso.

Podrías evitarla agregando:

```
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'
```

Una interpretación es, si construyes TensorFlow desde el fuente, puede ser más rápido en tu configuración. *Esas instrucciones marcadas, no están habilitadas por defecto en la compilación disponible, entiendo para compatibilizar con más CPU como sea posible.

> TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL, es la variable de entorno TensorFlow responsable de los registros.

- 1 para silenciar los info
- 2 para silenciar warning
- 3 para silenciar
  los errors **[not recomendado para nada]**

Esquema final sería:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'
import tensorflow as tf
```

Comment: Genial, muchisimas gracias, otra duda, como podría hacerlo para Java?

Comment: @ReinierHernándezÁvila no he utilizado Java con Tensorflow pero aquí puedes ver un poco más sobre el procedimiento de instalación y un típico helloworld. https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_java. Espero te sea util.